# How do I concatenate a line to the end of the next line using Find and Replace?

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editors, find-and-replace, text-editing

I have a file of the format:

```
Chapter 1
    12:45
First Video
    39:21
Second Video
```

The video lengths are preceded by tab characters. I want to convert this into:

```
Chapter 1
First Video    12:45
Second Video   39:21
```

In other words, concatenate a line to the end of the next line and so on using Find and Replace?

Answer (score 2):

Open Find and Replace dialog

- Find what: `(\t\d\d:\d\d)\r\n([^\n]+?)(\r\n|$)`
- Replace with: `\2\1\r\n`
- Check "Regular expression"

Then replace all

The match string finds a time preceding with a tab (`\t\d\d:\d\d`) then get the title in the next line. After all print the title and time in reverse order

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\t+\d\d:\d\d)\R(.+)$`
- Replace with: `$2$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  (                 # start group 1
    \t+             # 1 or more tabulations
    \d\d:\d\d       # 2 digits, a colon, 2 digits (the duration)
  )                 # end group 1
  \R                # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
  (.+)              # group 2, 1 or more any character but newline (the title)
$                   # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2          # content of group 2, the title
$1          # content of group 1, the duration
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. The second pattern is where I got flummoxed. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @KarthickS: You're welcome, glad it helps, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)